# Is it well-formed to overload an operator for a standard-defined type in global namespace that doesn't depend on a user-define type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is the following code well-formed program per the standard?

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp)
{
    return out << tp.time_since_epoch().count();
}
```

This isn't a template defined in the standard library, and isn't defined inside the namespace std, so it seems to be well-formed, but I might me missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything in the section named [**Constraints on programs**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/constraints) that forbids defining a function like yours.

I say, it is perfectly valid to do so.

Comment: I disagree.   The example shown adds a definition to namespace `std` (or a namespace within `std`)   The behaviour is therefore undefined.   It runs afoul of the first sentence of the text you linked to (specifically Section 17.6.4.2.1 para 1), since this type of example is not within any "specified otherwise" cases.

Comment: @Peter It only adds a definition to namespace std if you place it inside `namespace std { ... }`.